# Map Attachment to EmailMessage Record

Tags: apex, trigger, email, attachment, outlook

I have a kind of odd question.
We just implemented Service Cloud for about 15 users, as well as email to case.

Some of our users want to have the ability to upload existing /historical outlook messages to new case  records. We know that this can be done with Salesforce for outlook, but we **really** don't care to support Salesforce for Outlook - especially since this is a rare event.

We have a very strong development team, and we would honestly rather build and manage something ourselves to accomplish this functionality.

Here's what we were thinking:

1. Let the user create an attachment containing the .msg or .eml file on an existing case
2. Trigger on Attachment after insert or after update where associated file ischanged - only executes when ParentId is a case record and attachment is the .eml or .msg
3. *Parse Attachment body blob and map to EmailMessage* record and insert EmailMessage record associated to the parent case.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this functionality?

If there are no easier options, does anyone know of an open library which will do the parsing for us?

We write a lot of Apex, but we aren't experts in the .msg or .eml file format specifications, so parsing them would potentially be a challenge.